# How to change time format in swing

Tags: java, swing

I am using swing framework and applets.
If I take locale as `en_US`, the time shows in AM and PM.
If I take Locale as `ms_MY`, the time shows in Pagi and patang.

How can I show time in AM and PM when using locale `ms_MY`?

Please help me

Comment: What are you using to show the time?

Comment: Just 0.02$. Not every locale support displaying time in AM,PM format. A lot of locales format time in 24h manner.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you display the time using a `DateFormat` object. I even suppose you obtain your instance by calling the `DateFormat.getTimeInstance()` method. What you have to know is that a DateFormat instance, obtained through the various get*Instance static methods, is tied to a given Locale. As a consequence, if you want to have AM or PM displayed, you'll have to use the `getTimeInstance(int style, Locale aLocale)` version with Locale.en_US.

But be warned ! By using this method, your date will be displayed in english, as a consequence day names will be english ones. Is it really what you want ? I don't know, anyway that's what you'll get.

You can have better precision in output format by using `SimpleDateFormat`.

**EDIT** updated informations on SimpleDateFormat.

Contrary to what I said, it is possible to have AM and PM associated to non-english hour display. However, it is not immediate, as three of the four constructors of SimpleDateFormat use Locale obejct to get their infos. The only way to mix various languages informations is to use the `public SimpleDateFormat(String pattern, DateFormatSymbols formatSymbols)` constructor, which will allow you to define your own `DateFormatSymbols` instance. Constructing this object is left as an exercise.

The other three constructors use either the default Locale object or a given `Locale` object (of which, obviously, only the `DateFormatSymbols` will be used)

Comment: Can you explain how are you tied to locale with SimpleDateFormat?